# Inserting tables with group and subgroup codes in SAS

Tags: sas

First please consider the following list of **WC** variable...

```
1101    1201    1301    1401    1501    1601
1102    1202    1302    1402    1502    1602
1103    1203    1303    1403    1503    1603
1104    1204    1304    1404    1504    1604
1105    1205    1305    1405    1505    1605
1106    1206    1306    1406    1506    1606
1107    1207    1307    1407    1507    1607
1108    1208    1308    1408    1508    1608
1109    1209    1309    1409    1509    1609
1110    1210    1310    1410    1510    1610
1111    1211    1311    1411    1511    1611
1112    1212    1312    1412    1512    1612
1113    1213    1313    1413    1513    1613
1114    1214    1314    1414    1514    1614
1115    1215    1315    1415    1515    1615
1116    1216    1316    1416    1516    1616
1117    1217    1317    1417    1517    1617
1118    1218    1318    1418    1518    1618
1119                    
1120
```

Now understand what I am trying to achieve. 
I have a very long dataset where in i have two variables are shown in the below table...

```
WC     ASN  
1101    0       
1101    1       
1101    2       
1101    3       
1101    4       
1101    20      
1101    21      
1101    22      
1101    23      
1101    24      
1101    25      
1101    26      
1101    27      
1101    28      
1101    45      
1101    46      
1101    47      
1101    48      
1201    4       
1201    5       
1201    6       
1201    7       
1201    8       
1201    16      
1201    17      
1201    18      
1201    19      
1201    20      
1201    28      
1201    29      
1201    30      
1201    31      
1201    32      
1201    41      
1201    42      
1201    43      
1201    44      
1202    4       
1202    5       
1202    6       
1202    7       
1202    8       
1202    16      
1202    17      
1202    18      
1202    19      
1202    20      
1202    29      
1202    30      
1202    31      
1202    32      
1202    40      
1202    41      
1202    42      
1202    43      
1202    44
```

What I want to do is to add two more columns Group and SubGroup such that I get the final table as shown below:

```
WC  ASN Group   SubGroup
1101    0   1   1
1101    1   1   1
1101    2   1   1
1101    3   1   1
1101    4   1   1
1101    20  1   1
1101    21  1   1
1101    22  1   1
1101    23  1   1
1101    24  1   1
1101    25  1   1
1101    26  1   1
1101    27  1   1
1101    28  1   1
1101    45  1   1
1101    46  1   1
1101    47  1   1
1101    48  1   1
1201    4   1   2
1201    5   1   2
1201    6   1   2
1201    7   1   2
1201    8   1   2
1201    16  1   2
1201    17  1   2
1201    18  1   2
1201    19  1   2
1201    20  1   2
1201    28  1   2
1201    29  1   2
1201    30  1   2
1201    31  1   2
1201    32  1   2
1201    41  1   2
1201    42  1   2
1201    43  1   2
1201    44  1   2
1301    8   1   3
1301    9   1   3
1301    10  1   3
1301    11  1   3
1301    12  1   3
1301    13  1   3
1301    14  1   3
1301    15  1   3
1301    16  1   3
1301    32  1   3
1301    33  1   3
1301    34  1   3
1301    35  1   3
1301    36  1   3
1301    37  1   3
1301    38  1   3
1301    39  1   3
1301    40  1   3
1401    8   1   4
1401    9   1   4
1401    10  1   4
1401    11  1   4
1401    12  1   4
1401    13  1   4
1401    14  1   4
1401    15  1   4
1401    16  1   4
1401    33  1   4
1401    34  1   4
1401    35  1   4
1401    36  1   4
1401    37  1   4
1401    38  1   4
1401    39  1   4
1401    40  1   4
1501    4   1   5
1501    5   1   5
1501    6   1   5
1501    7   1   5
1501    8   1   5
1501    16  1   5
1501    17  1   5
1501    18  1   5
1501    19  1   5
1501    20  1   5
1501    29  1   5
1501    30  1   5
1501    31  1   5
1501    32  1   5
1501    40  1   5
1501    41  1   5
1501    42  1   5
1501    43  1   5
1501    44  1   5
1601    0   1   6
1601    1   1   6
1601    2   1   6
1601    3   1   6
1601    4   1   6
1601    20  1   6
1601    21  1   6
1601    22  1   6
1601    23  1   6
1601    24  1   6
1601    25  1   6
1601    26  1   6
1601    27  1   6
1601    28  1   6
1601    44  1   6
1601    45  1   6
1601    46  1   6
1601    47  1   6
1601    48  1   6
```

I was trying something like this...

```
 select;
    when (WC = 1101)  group = 1 subgroup=1;
    when (WC = 1201)  group = 1 subgroup=2;
    when (WC = 1301)  group = 1 subgroup=3;
    when (WC = 1401)  group = 1 subgroup=4;
    when (WC = 1501)  group = 1 subgroup=5;
    when (WC = 1601)  group = 1 subgroup=6;
    when (WC = 1102)  group = 2 subgroup=1;
    when (WC = 1202)  group = 2 subgroup=2;
    when (WC = 1302)  group = 2 subgroup=3;
    when (WC = 1402)  group = 2 subgroup=4;
    .
    .
    .
    when (WC = 1617)  group = 18 subgroup=5;
    when (WC = 1618)  group = 18 subgroup=6;
    when (WC = 1119)  group = 1 subgroup=1;
    otherwise group = 20 subgroup=1;
 end;
```

This is seriously long, tedious and confusing. I am sure there are better and short ways of doing it.

Please help.

---

As Joe and Keith suggested, I am adding this explanation.

**WC** in the table as the appear..

```
WC1     WC2     WC3     WC4     WC5     WC6   Group
1101    1201    1301    1401    1501    1601  1
1102    1202    1302    1402    1502    1602  2
1103    1203    1303    1403    1503    1603  3
.
.
.

WC     ASN  Group  SubGroup
1101    0     1     1        (because last two digits are 01 and 2nd degit is 1)
.
.
1206    1     6     2
.
.
1201    2     1     2
.
.
1213    3     13    2
.
.
1610    4     10    6
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a case for `substr` to me.

```
group = substr(wc,1,1);
subgroup = substr(wc,2,1);
```

Or whatever your rule is.  If your rule is more complicated than that, explain the rule.

Comment: unfortunately it did not work..... :(   `data want1;
   set have;
   by WC;
group = substr(WC, 1, 1);
subgroup = substr(WC, 2, 1);
run;`

Comment: @ZeekDSA as Joe pointed out, you need to better explain the rules here.  How, for example, does WC=1617 translate to group=18 and subgroup=5?

Comment: @Keith I added some explanation at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Joe I added some explanation at the bottom of my question which might help you.